# Capacitance of Two Spheres conducting spheres at distance $d$ and with radius $a$ where $d>a$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance

> I need to calculate the capacitance of two identical conducting spheres at distance $d$ with radius $a$ where $d>2a$. The final answer must be like this ($D=d/2a$). Can somebody help me or give me a reference?

[image]

Comment: Looks like the numerator can be taken out of the summation sign since it does not depend on $n$.

Comment: [Electrostatics of two charged conducting spheres](https://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~podgornik/download/Lekner-attraction.pdf) and the reference therein.